# Google Kickstart round-A 2020 Allocation

Tags: java, runtime-error

**Problem**
There are N houses for sale. The `i-th` house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend..

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

Time limit: 15 seconds per test set.

Memory limit: 1GB.
`1 ≤ T ≤ 100.`
`1 ≤ B ≤ 105.`
`1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000`, for all `i`.

Test set 1:
`1 ≤ N ≤ 100.`

Test set 2:
`1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5.`

I am trying to first sort the prices of the houses and then deducting the budget by the lowest priced house left in our array till all the budget is used. The interface is saying that I have a runtime error but with the sample test cases I ran on my ide it is not giving such thing. What can I do to solve this runtime error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Houses{

    public static void main(String []args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        int N, B;
        int []arr;
        int []result = new int[T];

        for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
            N = sc.nextInt();
            B = sc.nextInt();
            arr = new int[N];
        
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
        
            int houses=0, k=0;
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            while(B>=arr[k]){
               B = B-arr[k];
               k++;
               houses++;
            }
            result[i] = houses;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
            System.out.println("Case #" + (i+1) + ": " + result[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not mention the bounds for N. Also, you can use a counting sort here. This helps if N is large.

Comment: Thank you, I included the info about N. I don't know the algorithm for counting sort, will it remove the runtime error, given now the constraints for N.

Comment: Counting sort brings down the complexity from O(n log n) to O(n). Moreover you just need the first phase i.e. count how often each price appears in the input data. This is enough information to determine the max number of houses you can buy. So for large N this will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your algorithm to make it easier to test and more debug-friendly.

Multiple hints I can give you:

- If you wanna run tests, automate them as much as possible. I even wanted to remove the "amount of tests to run", but left it in so you can choose
- split up your algorithms in methods, so you can localize problems easier and run different tests
- Use your IDE's code formatting feature (format on save recommended, with customized formatting settings). That will clean up lots of visual problems, so you can see your errors easier
- Use proper names for your variables. Using single letters is a bad habit of mathematicians who cannot afford to write long variable names over and over. In programming it is much more important to have good names, so even if it gets complicated or you get errors, you do not lose track
- for fixed values, use constants (public static final)
- I included lots of messages/printing in the code, to showcase what's happening. This makes the code execution extremely slow, so for submitting the task I would comment them all out
- real tests would be done with JUnit, and without printing. And if some printing was done, Loggers would be used.

That's it from my part, enjoy:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Houses {

    static public final int BUDGET_MIN  = 1;
    static public final int BUDGET_MAX  = 105;

    static public final int HOUSE_PRICE_MIN = 1;
    static public final int HOUSE_PRICE_MAX = 1000;

    static public final int AMOUNT_HOUSES_MIN   = 1;
    static public final int AMOUNT_HOUSES_MAX   = 100;



    static public int prepareBuy() {
        final int numberOfHouses = getRandomIn(AMOUNT_HOUSES_MIN, AMOUNT_HOUSES_MAX);
        final int[] prices = new int[numberOfHouses];
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            final int price = getRandomIn(HOUSE_PRICE_MIN, HOUSE_PRICE_MAX);
            prices[i] = price;
        }
        final int availableBudget = getRandomIn(BUDGET_MIN, BUDGET_MAX);
        final int result = buyHouses(availableBudget, prices);
        return result;
    }

    static private int getRandomIn(final int pMin, final int pMax) {
        return (int) (pMin + Math.random() * (pMax - pMin + 1));
    }



    static public int buyHouses(final int pAvailableBudget, final int[] pHousePrices) {
        System.out.println("\t\tBudget (B):\t" + pAvailableBudget);
        System.out.println("\t\tHouses (N):\t" + pHousePrices.length);
        System.out.print("\t\tHouses for sale:\t");
        for (int i = 0; i < pHousePrices.length; i++) {
            final int price = pHousePrices[i];
            System.out.print(i + ":" + price + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        Arrays.sort(pHousePrices);
        System.out.print("\t\tHouses sorted:\t\t");
        for (int i = 0; i < pHousePrices.length; i++) {
            final int price = pHousePrices[i];
            System.out.print(i + ":" + price + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        int availableBudget = pAvailableBudget;
        int houses = 0, k = 0;
        while (pAvailableBudget >= pHousePrices[k]) {
            System.out.println("\t\tBuing house for " + pHousePrices[k] + "...");
            availableBudget = availableBudget - pHousePrices[k];
            k++;
            houses++;
            System.out.println("\t\t\tHouses bought: " + houses);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tBudget left: " + availableBudget);
        }
        final int result = houses;
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter number of tests: ");
        try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);) {
            final int tests = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            final int[] results = new int[tests];

            System.out.println("Running " + tests + " tests...");
            for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
                System.out.println("\tTest #" + (i + 1) + ":\t");
                final int housesBought = prepareBuy();
                results[i] = housesBought;
                System.out.println("\tTest #" + (i + 1) + " result: Bought " + housesBought + " houses\n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nAll tests complete.");
    }

}
```

Comment: neat code but not correct.